# How can i know some characters is in the string or not?

Tags: php

How can i know some characters are in the string or not?
i have 5 invalid characters for example that can not use in the username.
{-()*#} how can i do this?

Comment: Do you accept `風` in a username? I.e. are you sure these are the only special characters you want to check against? If so, I'd like to ask *why*?

Comment: The point being that perhaps you need the opposite approach - checking for *allowed* characters, not *disallowed* characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/[-()*#]/', $string)) {
    echo 'string contains one or more illegal characters';
}

if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', $string)) {
    echo 'string contains non-alphanumeric characters';
}
```

Comment: thanks can u tell me how can i check the email of user is valid or not? one@tow.three

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to check if every single character is a letter or a number you coud use:

```
if(ctype_alnum($text)){
   echo "Success!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$disallowed = array('-', '(', ')', '*', '#');
$valid = true;
foreach ($disallowed as $char) {
    if (strpos($username, $char) !== false) $valid = false;
}

if ($valid)
  echo 'valid username';
else 
  echo 'invalid username';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   if (preg_match('/(\{|\(|-|\)|\*|#|\})+/g', $string)) {
      echo 'invalid characters';
   }
```